# `isosurface` axis limits not matching input coordinates

Tags: matlab

Below code plots left with `if 1` and right with `if 0` - so axis limits depend on volume values... How to make it so they always match `X, Y, Z`?

[Docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html) suggest that axis limits should indeed follow `X, Y, Z`, so I wonder if there's caveats to forcing limits via `xlim` etc? If it's OK to use `xlim`, then is there a point to `X, Y, Z` if each of them are uniformly-sampled?

[image]

[D.zip](https://github.com/OverLordGoldDragon/ssqueezepy/files/13281701/D.zip) (unzip for `D.mat`)

```matlab
[X, Y, Z] = ndgrid(linspace(.5, 0, 9), linspace(.5, -.5, 12), ...
                   linspace(.5, 0, 16));
if 1
    D = load('D.mat').D;
else
    D = X.*Y.*Z;
    D = D * (100 / max(D, [], 'all'));
end

figure
view(3)
for ii = 10:10:100
    pkw = {'FaceAlpha',.1,'FaceColor','interp','LineStyle','none'};
    patch(isosurface(X, Y, Z, D, ii, D), pkw{:})
    patch(isocaps(X, Y, Z, D, ii), pkw{:})
end
```

Comment: I’m not exactly sure what you’re asking, but you seem surprised that MATLAB is setting the axis limits tightly around the plotted patches, rather than following the x, y and z values you give to the `isosurface` function. But that function just returns a set of patches. How is `patch`, the plotting function, supposed to know what your expected limits are? Use `xlim` and friends to set your desired axis limits.

Comment: Thanks. Well, I wonder what's the point of `X, Y, Z` in that case...

Comment: `Isosurface` uses those to put each vertex of the patches at the right coordinates. Leave them out and see what happens: `patch(isosurface(D, ii, D), pkw{:})`.

Comment: `isosurface‘ returns just a set of patches, as described in the docs: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isosurface.html#mw_32450d3a-676d-4aab-a5e2-c3cd85c538d3

Comment: Ok so they're to be used _with_ `xlim`-etc. Makes sense. I'll accept as answer.